# Root Huawei Honor 9 Lite without screen access

Tags: root-access, huawei

Is there a way to root the device without access to the screen itself (which is broken). All methods I've seen require access of device to allow rooting etc. I need some hack into the device, whilst connected to Mac or pc - need some pointers to info about that etc.

thanks in advance (finally got time to figure this out after a year of it being on a shelf)
Charlie

Answer (score 0):

In short - No, there isn't

Assuming you have previously unlocked bootloader (with unlock code from Huawei, which they don't provide anymore), there is still the encryption problem.

But your bootloader is locked, that means there is no hack into data partition.

In case you get TWRP booting from fastboot (which you don't), you could root /system and enable USB-debugging from TWRP, then remote control the device with scrcpy

Comment: You can try general unlock code, but this will ERASE data (in case unlocking is successful, which afaik only works for < 2014)
`fastboot oem get-bootinfo`
`fastboot oem unlock UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU`